# How to shorten a post form sent through xmlhttp?

Tags: javascript, forms, post, xmlhttprequest

So far I have this form to submit upvote when it is clicked below a comment. I have made it as pseudocode as possible so it avoids too localized problem:

```
<form id="upvote" method=post action="/comment_upvote">

    <input type="hidden" name="cid" value=%cid></input>
    <input type="hidden" name="bpid" value=%bpid></input>
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="">

</form>
```

and this Javascript xmlhttp code to handle it

```
var upvote = document.getElementById("upvote");

        upvote.onclick = function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost/comment_upvote", true)
            xmlhttp.send()
        }
```

I feel like this is not the best way especially talking about using a full blown POST form to handle an upvote.

My question is: What is a better and more readable way to POST this upvote form?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you really don't want to use a framework (no shame in that), here is something to start with (and no need to use a post method for a few data)

```
// Resuable crossbrowser XMLHttpRequest (Wikipedia)
if (typeof XMLHttpRequest === "undefined") {
  XMLHttpRequest = function () {
    try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0"); }
    catch (e) {}
    try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0"); }
    catch (e) {}
    try { return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
    catch (e) {}
    throw new Error("This browser does not support XMLHttpRequest.");
  };
}

// Resuable crossbrowser event listener manager (stackoverflow)
function addListener(elt, type, listener, useCapture) {
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        elt.addEventListener(type, listener, useCapture);
    } else if (window.attachEvent) {
        elt.attachEvent('on' + type, listener);
    }
}

// Resuable serialize-as-query-string function (w3school and myself)
function serialize(additionalParams) {
  var str = additionalParams || [];
  for (var i=0; i<this.length; i++) {
      var elt = this.elements[i],
          add = true;
      if ((elt.type == 'checkbox' || elt.type == 'radio') && !elt.checked) {
          add = false;
      }
      add && str.push(encodeURIComponent(elt.name) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(elt.value));
  }
  return str.join("&");
}

// Reusable submit handler
function sendXhr(e) {
    var form = e.target || e.srcElement;
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    var serializedForm = serialize.call(form, additionalParams);
    debug.innerHTML = serializedForm;
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        var done = this.done || 4;
        if (this.readyState === done){
            alert('XHR done, and got response!');
        }
    };
    request.open('GET', form.action + '?' + serializedForm, true);
    request.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    request.send(null);
}

// Code for this page    
var form = document.getElementById('upvote');

var additionalParams = ['foo=bar', 'sam=OK']; // Completely optional

addListener(form, 'submit', sendXhr);
```

N.B. : Do not use HTMLElement.onclick

See demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/8txdhxtz/

Answer (score 0):

It is fine like you did now.. but the Javascript is wrong because you're not passing POST variables to `xmlhttp.send()`

```
var upvote = document.getElementById("upvote");

        upvote.onclick = function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost/comment_upvote", true)
            xmlhttp.send()
        }
```

It should be

```
var upvote = document.getElementById("upvote");
var data_f = new FormData(upvote); // copy html form content to data_f var

        upvote.onclick = function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost/comment_upvote", true)
            xmlhttp.send(data_f) // send form with variables
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Jquery is probobly the framwork you are looking for.
it handels http requests along with DOM manipulation and lots of other stuff. check it out:
http://api.jquery.com/

what you want to do could be done with jQuery simply like this:

```
jQuery.post("http://localhost/comment_upvote" ,{cid:%cid,bpid:%bpid} );
```

assuming the server prints correctly %cid and %bpid in th JavaScript code.

dont forget adding the jquery library in to your html :)

Comment: Sorry, I need native Javascript for this use case, but take a +1 because this one will be suffice for other people :-)

Comment: how come?
I think then there is no bettr way :)

Comment: jQuery being "better" is highly subjective, but there is nothing about it that isn't native JavaScript.